# Adding Card details input in Custom Payment Method showing Error. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I'm creating a simple Custom Payment Method for that I've created an Extension which is working fine but I need input boxes for card details [This](https://webkul.com/blog/add-cc-form-custom-payment-method-magento2/) but now I'm facing an issue
on checkout it need to show like
[image]

copied image from above url but on my side it looks like

[image]

when I check the console it is showing an error

[image]

so now the *important* part when I checked my custom files it is showing that

`return window.checkoutConfig.payment.custompayment.availableTypes['custompayment'];`

was not working so in my console I've run `window.checkoutConfig.payment` then it was showing every payment method except mine `custompayment` what is the issue n how can I fix that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you implement all parts from the article?

In the article, you can find related code:

`etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test_module_configprovider" xsi:type="object">Test\Module\Model\TestpaymentConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

`Model/TestpaymentConfigProvider.php`

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Model;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source;
class TestpaymentConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /**
    * @param CcConfig $ccConfig
    * @param Source $assetSource
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Model\CcConfig $ccConfig,
        Source $assetSource
    ) {
        $this->ccConfig = $ccConfig;
        $this->assetSource = $assetSource;
    }
    /**
    * @var string[]
    */
    protected $_methodCode = 'testpayment';
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'payment' => [
                'testpayment' => [
                    'availableTypes' => [$this->_methodCode => $this->ccConfig->getCcAvailableTypes()],
                    'months' => [$this->_methodCode => $this->ccConfig->getCcMonths()],
                    'years' => [$this->_methodCode => $this->ccConfig->getCcYears()],
                    'hasVerification' => $this->ccConfig->hasVerification(),
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Please double check your ConfigProvider and sure that you are provide `custompayment` instead of `testpayment` in example

Comment: your are the best.. every time something silly I've done.. now Victor can you guide me I want to run my custom api (class) for payment how can I link that with my custom payment method *Place Order* button

Comment: It's very abstract question or I cannot catch essence of question. Please provide more accurate question or more details.

Comment: I just want to know that how to call custom php class on *Place Order* button so on my custom payment method when I click Place order then apply custom functionality through my php class

Comment: Victor one more thing these fields are not required how to make them required

Comment: See `data-validate` part in original article, it should add validation to fields